# evolution-calender-factory using too much memory

Tags: 16.04, evolution

Location : /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory

this eats too much memory, after a bit of research i have found out some options both of them are not tested by me.

1st: this process gets stuck but if u run it manually it terminates after some initialization. but i dont know how to run it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1342123

2nd: change the name of the folder so its not found at start up.
i want to do the first one but dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking the procedures from the link you posted, I hatched together following solution:

First disable showing events in the `indicator-datetime` with `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-events false` - as this is keeping evolution-calendar-factory up running.

Second create a autostart instance of evolution-calendar-factory so the hung process gets flushed, therefor `nano ~/.config/autostart/evolution-calendar-factory.desktop`  and copy and paste the following into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=bash -c 'sleep 1m; /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory'
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Workaround for evolution-calendar-factory
```

now we have to make the file executable with `chmod a+x ~/.config/autostart/evolution-calendar-factory.desktop` and on the next restart it should work.

P.S: the link you posted is for the phone and tablet version here is the link to the desktop bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1589605

Comment: this is the 'solution' from the  bug you linked - yet it appears to not work

Comment: what do you mean? if so do you have a solution?

Comment: it works, made an error on my machine; but pls check for yourself again

Comment: it worked for me